# UITableView with ScrollView deselect Problems

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift4

`UITableView` `checkmark` happening is  deselect when I was scrolling

> Code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return dizi.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text=dizi[indexPath.row]
   
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }
}
```

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp0sr.png)

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzmnh.png)

how can i fix it ? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because in UITableView Cell gets reused when you scroll and its your responsibility to ensure it restores its UI state when reused

So create a array to hold the selected indexPath

```
var selectedIndex : [IndexPath]! = [IndexPath]()
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    if if selectedIndex.contains(indexPath) {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }
    else {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text=dizi[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Finally update the selectedIndexArray

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        self.selectedIndex = selectedIndex.filter({
            return $0 != indexPath
        })
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        self.selectedIndex.append(indexPath)
    }

}
```

Comment: @tiskender2 : Always welcome buddy :) I am glad I could be of help :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Because you also need to set `UITableViewCellAccessoryType` in `cellForRowAt`. because if use scroll up/down table then cell will be reuse so.

How to do it ? take one array same size of rows and repeat with value 0 and when you do check any row then update value 1 with `indexPath.row` and if you uncheck any row then update value 0 with `indexPath.row`

and in `cellForRowAt` method before `return cell` put condition like

```
if checkUncheckArr[indexPath.row] == 0 {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.non

}
else {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

}
```